# Prove that exponent is less than number of digits of a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

I am trying to find a proof for below statement. i.e. Given integer N that is a perfect power, show that the exponent is less than the number of digits in N

```
Show that if N = M^e for some integers M,e > 1 then e ≤ |N| + 1
```

Not able to find any hints for the same. Any help?

FYI. This question if from book : 'Introduction to Modern Cryptography, Second Edition By Jonathan Katz, Yehuda Lindell' 
Exercise 8.12 a)

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OWZYBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=THis+exercise+develops+an+efficient+algorithm+for+testing&source=bl&ots=BbpgCOX_2m&sig=B8y4vfYjES-hqDV_nvup0gZa2yg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6ODT4L7LAhWKC44KHb3LCfcQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=THis%20exercise%20develops%20an%20efficient%20algorithm%20for%20testing&f=false

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is only true for $M\geq 0$.

Comment: This depends on the basis. For example, if you mean base 10 digits, then obviously this is false, since $8=2^3$ has only one digit. Actually, this is true only for base 2 digits, and the proof is trivial.

Comment: Induction on $e$?

Comment: @All sorry for the typo, it's |N| + 1 and not just |N|

Comment: If you work in base 2, then you have two possibilities: if $M=1$, then everything is trivial. If $M \ge 2$, then $M^e \ge 2^e=100 \dots 00$, where you have exactly $e$ zeroes.

Comment: Seems my interpretation of |N| is wrong. Please correct me. Check the original question from the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $||N||$ represent the number of digits in $N$, then we have:$$\begin{align}
N&=M^e\\
\therefore \log_{10}N&=e\log_{10}M\\
\therefore e&=\frac{\log_{10}N}{\log_{10}M}\lt\frac{||N||}{\log_{10}M}\\
\end{align}$$Now this will give $e\lt||N||$ only when $\log_{10}M\ge1$ which means it is only valid for $M\ge10$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a number $A$ has $d$ digits if and only if
$$2^{d-1} \le A < 2^d-1 $$
Now, if $M \ge 2$ you have
$$M^e \ge 2^e$$
so that $M^e$ as at least $e+1$ digits.

Comment: Your book is a cryptography book, hence it is obvious that the base is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $N = 16$, $M = 2$, and $e = 4$, we have $N = 2^4$ and $N$ has two digits. We see that $e > 2$, and the claim is false.

Comment: hii, sorry for the typo, it's |N| + 1

Comment: For the same example, this is still false (we still have e > 3).